# The code runs fine on my system but gives segmentation fault on USACO. Whats the issue?

Tags: c++

This  code I am trying to run on UASCO, don't know whats the issue its failing with segmentation fault. 
 Help me on this
Also it should be helpful to know how to debug the segmentation issue.
Is there any good tutorial which can give me the basics and show me how to debug.

```
 # include <iostream>
# include <string>
# include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct member
{
string mainMem;
int amount;
int myAmount;
int noOfMem;
string toGiveMem[10];
};

 int main()
 {
ofstream fout ("gift1.out");
ifstream fin ("gift1.in");
int totalMem;
member allMem[totalMem];
string name;
fin>>totalMem;

for( int i = 0; i<totalMem; i++)
{
    fin>>allMem[i].mainMem;
    allMem[i].myAmount = 0;
}

while(!fin.eof())
{
    fin>>name;
    for( int i = 0; i<totalMem; i++)
    {
        if(name.compare(allMem[i].mainMem)==0)
        {
            fin>>allMem[i].amount;
            fin>>allMem[i].noOfMem;
            for(int j = 0; j< allMem[i].noOfMem; j++)
                fin>>allMem[i].toGiveMem[j];
        }
    }

}
// all input taken.
cout<<" Do processing."<<endl;
for(int i = 0; i< totalMem; i++)
{

    int x =0;
    if(allMem[i].noOfMem != 0)
        x = allMem[i].amount/allMem[i].noOfMem;

    allMem[i].myAmount += allMem[i].amount- (x*allMem[i].noOfMem);

    for(int j = 0; j <allMem[i].noOfMem; j++)
    {

        for(int k = 0; k< totalMem; k++)
        {

            if(allMem[i].toGiveMem[j].compare(allMem[k].mainMem) == 0)
            {
                allMem[k].myAmount += x;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should cut and paste your code, This code is missing a closing bracket ... not to mention it's a bit ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the already accepted answer:

Whenever you read from a file, you must make sure that the read succeeded. Otherwise you must not use the variable.

Bad code:

```
int totalMembers;
fin >> totalMembers;
```

Good code:

```
int totalMembers;
if (fin >> totalMembers) {
  // now totalMembers is guaranteed to be defined
}
```

Also, you should never use the `eof` function in a loop. Instead, use checks like the above when reading into your variables. If that fails (returns `false`), you have either reached the end of file or you have an I/O error. In that case you may use `eof` or `bad` to distinguish these cases.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at these lines:

```
int totalMem;
member allMem[totalMem];
string name;
fin>>totalMem;
```

What is `totalMem` when the array is declared?

I would have thought this would show up as a compiler warning.

Comment: Thanks Man, I just need to reorder the statements as:int totalMem;
string name;
fin>>totalMem;member allMem[totalMem];